# Stripe Alamofire JSON not populating array

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview, stripe-payments

I am trying to populate a UITableView with a list of credit cards in Stripe.  I know it works for my test environment because I am able to see a JSON response from Postman.  It for some reason is not populating my table.

Since this is an [Any Object] I do not need to create a separate class with init stings?  I have other tables in my app populating data and updated UILabels after pulling info from FireBase.

Here is the code in the PaymentsVC.swift View Controller:

```
class PaymentVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet var headerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var cardsTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var cardTextField: STPPaymentCardTextField!

    var stripeTool = StripeTools()
    static let sharedClient = MyAPIClient()

    //var customerId: String?
    let customerId = "mycusid"

    var baseURLString: String? = "https://api.sripe.com/v1/customers"
    var baseURL: URL {
        if let urlString = self.baseURLString, let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            return url
        } else {
            fatalError()
        }
    }

    var stripeUtil = StripeUtil()
    var cards = [AnyObject]()



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        //only one section
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return self.cards.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let url = self.baseURL.appendingPathComponent("\(self.customerId)/sources?object=card")
        let headers = ["Authorization": self.stripeTool.getBasicAuth()]
        Alamofire.request(url, headers: headers)
            .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
            .responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let result):
                    if let cards = STPCustomer.decodedObject(fromAPIResponse: result as? [String: AnyObject]) {
                        print(cards)
                    //    completion(cards, nil)
                    } else {
                    //    completion(nil, NSError.customerDecodingError)
                    }
                case .failure(let error): break
                   // nil, error
                }
        }


        //get card cell with cardCell identifier don't forget it on your storyboard
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cardCell") as! CardCell

        //get the last4 value on the card json, create the string and pass it to the label
        if let last4 = self.cards[indexPath.row]["last4"] {
            cell.cardNumberLabel.text = "**** **** **** \(last4!)"
        }

        //get the month/year expiration values on the card json, create the string and pass it to the label
        if let expirationMonth = self.cards[indexPath.row]["exp_month"], let expirationYear = self.cards[indexPath.row]["exp_year"] {
            cell.expirationLabel.text = "\(expirationMonth!)/\(expirationYear!)"
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: where you called `cardsTableView.reloadData()`?

Comment: @wings Good call out, I can't believe I missed that.  I just added it to the viewDidLoad and it still does not work.  When i run the app I just see a bunch of lines like you would see on an Excel Spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put api calls inside `cellForRowAt` as it'll be called every cell creation/dequeuing, you need to put this code inside `viewDidLoad` , with reloading the table

```
let url = self.baseURL.appendingPathComponent("\(self.customerId)/sources?object=card")
let headers = ["Authorization": self.stripeTool.getBasicAuth()]
Alamofire.request(url, headers: headers)
    .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
    .responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let result):
            if let cards = STPCustomer.decodedObject(fromAPIResponse: result as? [String: AnyObject]) {
                print(cards)
                self.cards = cards
                self.cardsTableView.reloadData()
            //    completion(cards, nil)
            } else {
            //    completion(nil, NSError.customerDecodingError)
            }
        case .failure(let error): break
           // nil, error
        }
}
```

---

don't forget to set in `viewDidLoad`

```
 self.cardsTableView.delegate = self
 self.cardsTableView.dataSource = self
```

Comment: i have done what you suggested and moved the code, but the data still is not populating. I am going to add a print command to see if i can see the JSON populating

Comment: i updated the code to print, but it will still not display.  I suspect that there is something wrong with how the JSON is being interpreted.

Comment: thank you for the edit, but it gives me an error. Cannot assign value of type 'STPCustomer' to type '[AnyObject]'

Comment: I think it is because of my variable that I declaried AnyObject as part of the array var cards = [AnyObject]()

Comment: you decode response as dictionary so how you make the cards as array ??

Comment: check if it could be **[[String: AnyObject]]**

Comment: is that the issue?  is that the issue?  I am a little green on the UITableViews .

Comment: Cannot assign value of type 'STPCustomer' to type '[[String : AnyObject]]' . so that did not work either.  I will have to look up the STPCustomer class

Comment: i don't know your json decoding , but you need to have an array for the tableview